# Add Service Reference to windows Phone Project/Portable DLL fails

Tags: c#, rcp, webservice-client, service-reference

I have a problem, when I add a service reference to my windows Phone 7 project it doesn't generate any of the expected Methods.

I tried  to create it in a portable Library but still the same, I tried this again with a Win Form Project and everything is working well! but not in Portable Libraries or Windows Phone 7 ...

How can i consume it correctly considering RCP or Encoding?

> Warning   1 Custom tool warning: Contract
>   'AuthenticationStepOneServiceCaller' is not compatible with portable
>   libraries because it contains one or more operations that have
>   'Use=OperationFormatUse.Encoded' or 'Style=OperationFormatStyle.Rpc'
>   in
>   'XmlSerializerFormatAttribute'.   2012\Projects\PortableClassLibrary5\PortableClassLibrary5\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap 1   1

on Win Phone Project

> Warnung   1   Warnung für benutzerdefiniertes Tool: Contract 'AuthenticationStepOneServiceCaller' is not compatible with Silverlight 3 because it contains one or more operations with SOAP Encoding (use='encoded'). Only the non-encoded operations will be generated.  2010\Projects\PhoneApp2\PhoneClassLibrary1\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap    1   1   PhoneClassLibrary1

(Warnung = Warning, benutzerdefiniertes = userdefined)

Comment: the Address: https://81.192.184.21:8443/ProxyWS/services/AuthenticationStepOneServiceCaller?wsdl